# How to Embed a Google Doc into a Wordpress Page

Tags: wordpress, embed, google-docs

Can Someone please explain to me why my google doc is not embedding into wordpress?

[picture of wordpress page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTWGq.png)

embedded code from publish to web on google:

```
 <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQV4p--a7Ce0lwafCZme-_Gja8-jZ8W07WhDygdX5ziRDN-hELZmdK9NF3whSCH7JSGnWlJmLGRYMve/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Don't think you can embed it by using the <code> tag. Code tag is for displaying code snippets on your posts/pages. To make this work you will have to edit one of the PHP files and add it there. Not sure which one would be the best file to do it but something like header or footer but wait till someone else replies.

Comment: I have tried that several times and it doesnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to embed Google Docs in WordPress is to use Embed Code provided by Google Docs.

Before you share, make sure the file is viewable by public.

Go to your Docs, File -> Publish on Web -> Embed and copy the code.

Now paste that code in HTML tab of your editor.

The iframe code you posted should work fine.